# Как Wordpress изменить robots.txt?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, поисковая-оптимизация

Как в robots.txt вставить ссылки на XML sitemap в Wordpress?

Также в файле robots.txt необходимо добавить запрет на индексацию
1страниц фильтрации
2сортировки
3пагинации
4админ панели

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> как в robots.txt вставить ссылки на XML sitemap в Wordpress?

Можно создать robots.txt с нужным содержимым.

Можно использовать СЕО-плагины с такой возможностью.